# What are primitive, internal, builtin, and special functions?

Tags: r, r-faq

I have seen that some functions that call C-code are described as `primitive`, `internal`, `builtin`, or `special`.  What are these functions?

Answer (score 26):

This question conflates two distinct concepts. `special` and `builtin` are two of the three types of function (along with `closure`s), as determined by [`typeof`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/typeof).

From [R-ints, 1.5 Argument evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-ints.html#Argument-evaluation)

> being a special/builtin is separate from being primitive or 
>   .Internal: quote is a special primitive, + is a builtin 
>   primitive, cbind is a special .Internal and grep is a builtin 
>   .Internal.

### Builtin vs. Special

If a function calls C-code, builtin/special refers to whether or not its arguments are evaluated before being passed to the C-code.

From [R-lang, 2.1.7 Builtin objects and special forms](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Builtin-objects-and-special-forms)

> Builtin functions have all their arguments evaluated and passed 
>   to the internal function, in accordance with call-by-value, 
>   whereas special functions pass the unevaluated arguments to the 
>   internal function.

### Internal vs. Primitive

[`.Internal`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/Internal) and [`.Primitive`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/Primitive) refer to the interface used to call C-code.  Internal is the standard approach, since you can check arguments in R-code before you call the C-code.  Primitive is higher performance, but does not allow any R-code in the function.

From [R-ints, 2 .Internal vs .Primitive](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive)

> C code compiled into R at build time can be called directly in 
>   what are termed primitives or via the .Internal interface, which 
>   is very similar to the .External interface except in syntax. More 
>   precisely, R maintains a table of R function names and 
>   corresponding C functions to call, which by convention all start 
>   with ‘do_’ and return a [SEXP](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-ints.html#SEXPs). This table (R_FunTab in file 
>   [src/main/names.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/names.c#L36-L975)) also specifies how many arguments to a function 
>   are required or allowed, whether or not the arguments are to be 
>   evaluated before calling, and whether the function is ‘internal’ 
>   in the sense that it must be accessed via the .Internal interface,
>   or directly accessible in which case it is printed in R as 
>   .Primitive.
>
> Functions using .Internal() wrapped in a closure are in general 
>   preferred as this ensures standard handling of named and default 
>   arguments.
>
> However, for reasons of convenience and also efficiency (as there 
>   is some overhead in using the .Internal interface wrapped in a 
>   function closure), the primitive functions are exceptions that can 
>   be accessed directly.

Comment: You write great [r-faq] posts, But why do you make them community-wiki? You've spent ample amount of time and energy on this, why would you want to deny the tiny amount of rep given to you as part of upvotes on the answer? Or do you want to signal to others that, *this is what I've written, Please go ahead and improve it*?

Comment: @BhargavRao Yup, I want other people to improve on it! If it's tagged `r-faq`, it's important to have an answer that the community is happy with. And I get plenty of points from other answers.

Comment: There’s more: some primitives are defined as functions in R, others are defined directly as `.Primitive` objects. Can you expand on the difference? I’ve tried finding an explanation, and experimenting with them in R, but don’t understand it. As an example, ``​`+`​`` is defined as a *function*, whereas ``​`(`​`` and `return` are not (despite being callable).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Those things are functions. Take a look at `is.function(\`(\`)` and `is.function(return)`. No idea why the print method for them just says `.Primitive()` though.

Comment: @RichieCotton Yes, that’s what I was referring to: of course they’re functions but their R definitions don’t look like functions. Actually it’s the other way: `.Primitive(…)` *returns a function*. Consequently, I don’t understand how (e.g.) `c` works: for example, if I copy its definition and assign it to a different variable, the result doesn’t work: `x = function(...) .Primitive("c"); x(1, 2)` returns `.Primitive("c")`. If, by contrast, I directly define `y = .Primitive("c")`, it works. So what does `c` do? Also, `x` and `c` are actually printed subtly differently in the console.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think you want `x = function(...) .Primitive("c")(...); x(1, 2)` or simply `x = .Primitive("c"); x(1, 2)`. This is getting into new question territory though. See if you can clarify what exactly it is you want to know!

Comment: @RichieCotton I’m thinking about posting a new question. But just to clarify: I’m not asking *how to make this work* (I already did, see previous comment) but how it works under the hood.

Comment: @KonradRudolph have you elucidated these questions ? I'm confused about those as well

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I’m afraid I never have, asking a well-researched question about this is quite a lot of effort and I never found time before forgetting about it.

Comment: I might have the start of an answer here : https://twitter.com/antoine_fabri/status/1197544244879212546